# Dots instead of digits for highly upvoted post in the profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Most popular [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s post contains dots instead of digits in the iOS app:

> [image: topost]

- App Version: 1.6.3.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.3.6.

The minimum font scale wasn't sufficient.